# Why can't i bind the result of a function to my TextView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to self-teach Kotlin with the Google Android Dev Courses (I started a week ago and have very little experience in coding).
At the end of the course that thaught me to build a working Tip Calculator, there was an optional exercise to create a similar app.
I chose to create an Animal Age Calculator but i can't manage to bind the result to its TextView.

The output that i get is `Animal age: %s` .
The ouput that i want is the result of either my `catAgeFormula(age)` or my `dogAgeFormula(age)`
I understand it's showing me this : `<string name="animal_age">Animal age: %s</string>`
But the thing i don't understand is why my binding doesn't work `binding.ageResult.text = getString(R.string.animal_age)`

Here is the complete function i'm not sure about :

```
private fun calculateAge() {
    val stringInTextField = binding.userAge.text.toString()
    val age = stringInTextField.toIntOrNull()

    if (age == null || age == 0) {
        binding.ageResult.text = "0"
        return
    }

    when (binding.animalOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
    R.id.option_cat -> catAgeFormula(age)
    else -> dogAgeFormula(age)
    }

    binding.ageResult.text = getString(R.string.animal_age)
}
```

And the output TextView :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/age_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/calculate_button"
    tools:text="Animal age : 42 years" />
```

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so i'm really sorry if messed up something.
Thanks in advance for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an argument on the `getString` method

```
private fun calculateAge() {
    val stringInTextField = binding.userAge.text.toString()
    //...
    binding.ageResult.text = getString(R.string.animal_age, stringInTextField)
}
```

Your string is:

```
<string name="animal_age">Animal age: %s</string>
```

The `%s` means it expects to receive 1 `String` type argument. The method `getString` can receive 2 arguments. The first is the id of the resource string and the second a `vararg` that can be any number of other arguments. This is because a string defined on the resources can take up any number of other arguments, by example:

```
<string name="example">Example %1$s %2$d</string>
```

Where `%2$d` it would be a number expected as a second argument

```
val example = getString(R.string.example, "one", 2)
//Example one 2
```

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) for further explanations

Comment: Thanks to you, i managed to find out is was missing a variable to store the result of my "when" statement.
I'll remember that the "getString" needs more than one argument !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cutiko, i found out i was missing a variable for the code to work properly.
I added my `when` statement into a variable named `animalAge` and used it as a second argument to my `getString` method.

Here is the final working function :

```
private fun calculateAge() {
    val stringInTextField = binding.userAge.text.toString()
    val age = stringInTextField.toIntOrNull()
    //...
    val animalAge = when (binding.animalOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        R.id.option_cat -> catAgeFormula(age)
        else -> dogAgeFormula(age)
    }
    binding.ageResult.text = getString(R.string.animal_age, animalAge)
}
```

And the final working string resource :

`<string name="animal_age">Animal age: %d</string>`